# Every other date but should always include final date

Tags: javascript, logic

This is really just a logic question.

I have a set of dates *which can vary*. Three examples are the following:

```
1-Jan | 2-Jan | 3-Jan | 4-Jan | 5-Jan | 6-Jan | 7-Jan | 8-Jan

1-Jan | 2-Jan | 3-Jan | 4-Jan | 5-Jan | 6-Jan | 7-Jan | 8-Jan | 9-Jan

1-Jan | 2-Jan | 3-Jan
```

I would like logic so that every-other date is returned but the final date should always be included. So the above three would be transformed to the following:

```
      | 2-Jan |       | 4-Jan |       | 6-Jan |       | 8-Jan

1-Jan |       | 3-Jan |       | 5-Jan |       | 7-Jan |       | 9-Jan

1-Jan |       | 3-Jan
```

The sets can be any length up to 60 (the current set I'm working with has a length of 31)

I'm using D3.js and tried to use odd/even to decide which dates to return:

```
var setLength = dataSet.length;       
var divisor = (setLength%2==0 ? 2 : 3);
```

Then I use divisor in a function:

```
function(d,i) {
     if(i%divisor == 0) return d.date);
}
```

How can I change the above so it always returns everyother date including the last member of the set?

Comment: Are the sets stored in an array?

Comment: @guest271314 yes in an array - hence the `(d,i)` - `i` being the index of each member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were just using the wrong test against the index. If the set length is even filter odds: `%2!=0`, if odd filter evens: `%2==0`

```js
let data = [
  ["1 - Jan", "2 - Jan", "3 - Jan", "4 - Jan", "5 - Jan", "6 - Jan", "7 - Jan", "8 - Jan"],
  ["1 - Jan", "2 - Jan", "3 - Jan", "4 - Jan", "5 - Jan", "6 - Jan", "7 - Jan", "8 - Jan", "9 - Jan"],
  ["1 - Jan", "2 - Jan", "3 - Jan"],
  ["1 - Jan", "2 - Jan", "3 - Jan","4 - Jan"]
];

let filtered = data.map(dates => {
  let odd = dates.length%2!=0;
  return dates
    .filter((e, index) => odd ? index%2==0 : index%2!=0)
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate from array `.length - 1` to `-1`, decrement initialization variable by `2` at final expression at each iteration; push elements to a new array, return array in reverse order

```js
var arr = [
  ["1-Jan", "2-Jan", "3-Jan", "4-Jan"
   , "5-Jan", "6-Jan", "7-Jan", "8-Jan"]

  , ["1-Jan", "2-Jan", "3-Jan", "4-Jan"
     , "5-Jan", "6-Jan", "7-Jan", "8-Jan", "9-Jan"]

  ,["1-Jan", "2-Jan", "3-Jan"]
];

function everyOtherFromEnd(arr) {
  for (var n = arr.length - 1, res = []; n > -1; res.unshift(arr[n]), n -= 2);
  return res
}

arr.forEach(function(curr) {
  console.log(everyOtherFromEnd(curr))
})
```

Comment: Note you could use `res.unshift()` instead of `push()` that way no need to call `res.reverse()`